# Angular: Access template elements created using ng-For = obj from Component

Tags: angular, typescript

Directive Template-

```
  <li *ngFor = "#el of dragZoneElems; #idx = index">
     <h4 [style.position]="'fixed'" [style.top.px]="idx* 30"   [style.margin-top] = "80.0" [style.z-index] = 100 [dragResponder] = "el">{{el.first}} {{el.last}}</h4>
  </li>
```

I need to access the created h4 element using object value from the directive class. How do I do this.

Comment: its not clear what you are trying to say.

Comment: We create each element using ngFor = el of Elems. From my component I need to access the created element using the el object. That is I need to know the created element corresponding to object that was used to create it.

Comment: So you mean to say which `el` belongs to which `h4` ?

Comment: Yes. So lets say dragZoneElems[4] would correspond to which h4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "access" but I assume this is what you want:

```
 <li *ngFor = "#el of dragZoneElems; #idx = index">
     <!-- added: #h4 -->
     <h4 #h4 [style.position]="'fixed'" [style.top.px]="idx* 30"   [style.margin-top] = "80.0" [style.z-index] = 100 [dragResponder] = "el">{{el.first}} {{el.last}}</h4>
  </li>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  @ViewChildren('h4') h4s;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.h4s.length);
  }
}
```

Comment: We create each element using ngFor = el of Elems. From my component I need to access the created element using the el object. That is I need to know the created element corresponding to object that was used to create it.

Comment: If the element you create is not an Angular component or doesn't have a directive added which allows you to set a property, then you need to add some id to an attribute `[attr.some-id]="el.id"` that can be stored or retrieved as string because attributes can only store strings. Then you can search `h4s` for the element that has the id you're looking for.